# RewriteRule does not redirect directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htacces with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

This redirects `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/file.php`, but not `www.domain.com/directory/`.

Why? And how do I include the directory in the rewrite rule?

Comment: Do you have another htaccess file in the `/directory/` ?

Comment: @starkeen No, there is nothing else. But it is not the root of the server, just of my web space on a shared hosting server, so I don't know what may be in the Apache configuration file or elsewhere.